# Способ получить все внутренние ссылки на сайте

Tags: url, парсер, ruby

Привет.

Какие есть способы спарсить все внутренние ссылки на сайте?

Я вижу только одну глупую затею, это определить (домен.зону) сайта, далее начиная с самой главной страницы искать ссылки по шаблону из регулярок, 
проверять уникальность ссылки (чтобы не делать повторные переходы), делать переход и там искать еще ссылки, и так, пока не наступит конец света).

Как реализовать более практичней и эффективней?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот тут народ обсуждает: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700367/getting-all-links-of-a-webpage-using-ruby

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780067/getting-all-the-links-of-a-web-page-in-ruby-without-using-inbuilt-library

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781236/how-can-i-get-all-links-of-a-website-using-ruby-mechanize-gem

Всё найдено с помощью строки "ruby get all links from site", набранной в Гугле...

Comment: Все больше никаких запросов в поисковике на русском языке, еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Я, обычно, сначала спрашиваю Яндекс по-русски, если ответ не найден -- перехожу на английский и Гугл.